# Count how many car/cars owner owns

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I'm trying to learn plsql and got stuck in understanding some basic stuff. Here is a challenge that I'm trying to solve. I have two tables. One holds information about owners and the other is information about cars.

I want to to write an anonymous block that joins these two tables and with a for loop based on amount of cars that is registered to each owner prints how many cars each person own. furthermore I want an if statement which distinguishes between 1 Car (singular) and 2, 3 Cars (plural).

the tables are these:

```
CREATE TABLE owners(
    id_nr VARCHAR2(13) PRIMARY KEY,
    f_name VARCHAR2(20),
    s_name VARCHAR2(20)
);
    
CREATE TABLE cars(
    reg_nr VARCHAR2(6) PRIMARY KEY,
    id_nr REFERENCES owners(pnr),
    model VARCHAR2(20),
    year NUMBER(4),
    date DATE
);
```

The result may look like something like this:

```
19380321-7799, Hans, Anderson, Owns: 1 car
19490321-7899, Mike, Erikson, Owns: 2 cars
```

. . . etc

I know the this question was already answered but when I try following:

```
declare
    v_suffix varchar2(1);
begin
    for o in (select bilägare_pnr, fnamn, enamn,
                (select count(1) from fordon where fordon_pnr = bilägare_pnr) as bilar_ägda
                from bilägare)
    loop
        if o.pnr_fordon = 1 
            then v_suffix = 'bil'
            else v_suffix = 'bilar'
        end if;
        dbms_output.put_line(o.pnr || ', ' || o.fnamn || ', ' || o.enamn
            || ' Äger: ' || o.pnr_fordon || ' bil' || v_suffix);
    end loop;
end;
/
```

I get:

```
ORA-06550: line 9, column 27:
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "=" when expecting one of the following:

   := . ( @ % ;
```

any tips? Im not sure how to declare v_suffix

### EDIT (copied from comment on answer below):

Updating my code:

```
declare
  cursor c_BILÄGARE is
    select fnamn,enamn,pnr
      from BILÄGARE;
begin
  for rec in c_BILÄGARE loop
    if (rec.antal>1) then
     dbms_output.put_line (rec.pnr||','|| rec.fnamn || ',' ||
                           rec.enamn || ',' || rec.antal || 'bilar');
    else
      dbms_output.put_line (rec.pnr||','|| rec.fnamn || ',' ||
                            rec.enamn || ',' || rec.antal || 'bil');
    end if;
  end loop;
end;
```

getting:

```
ORA-06550: line 9, column 9: PLS-00302: component 'ANTAL' must be declared (antal=Quantity)
```

Answer (score 0):

As noted above, you need to use `:=` as the assignment operator. You also need a semi-colon after each statement - thus, you should use

```
then v_suffix := 'bil';
```

instead of

```
then v_suffix := 'bil'
```

So your code should look like:

```
declare
    v_suffix varchar2(1);
begin
    for o in (select bilägare_pnr, fnamn, enamn,
                (select count(1)
                   from fordon
                   where fordon_pnr = bilägare_pnr) as bilar_ägda
                from bilägare)
    loop
        if o.pnr_fordon = 1 
            then v_suffix := 'bil';
            else v_suffix := 'bilar';
        end if;

        dbms_output.put_line(o.pnr || ', ' || o.fnamn || ', ' || o.enamn
            || ' Äger: ' || o.pnr_fordon || ' bil' || v_suffix);
    end loop;
end;
```

Comment: Updating my code: declare 
cursor c_BILÄGARE is select 
fnamn,enamn,pnr
from BILÄGARE;

begin
for rec in c_BILÄGARE loop

if (rec.antal>1) then
dbms_output.put_line (rec.pnr||','||
rec.fnamn||','||rec.enamn||','||rec.antal||'bilar');
else
dbms_output.put_line (rec.pnr||','||
rec.fnamn||','||rec.enamn||','||rec.antal||'bil');
end if;
end loop;
end;    getting: ORA-06550: line 9, column 9:
PLS-00302: component 'ANTAL' must be declared (antal=Quantity)

Comment: Please don't use comments to update your question - instead, use the `edit` button to edit your question (as I have done in this case), and then leave a comment stating that you've updated your question. Thanks. Now - as to the error you're getting now - it seems that you're not selecting `ANTAL` in cursor `c_BILÄGARE`. Add `antal` to the cursor and you should be fine. Also - it would be helpful if you'd update the question to show the real layout of your tables instead of an English translation. We don't care if code or tables are in Swedish - it's all just character strings to us. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Please try this piece of code:

```
begin

for rec in (select
    o.id_nr ||  ',' || o.f_name || ',' || o.s_name || ', Owns: ' || coalesce(car.cnt, 0) || ' ' || decode(car.cnt , 1, 'Car', 'Cars') as res
    from owners o
    left outer join (select id_nr, count(1) as cnt from cars group by id_nr) car on (car.id_nr = o.id_nr)) loop
   dbms_output.put_line(rec.res);
end loop;
end;
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple issues in your code which is highlighted and fixed in following code:

```
declare
    v_suffix varchar2(5); -- data length should be 5 or more
begin
    for o in (select bilägare_pnr, fnamn, enamn,
                (select count(1) from fordon where fordon_pnr = bilägare_pnr) as bilar_ägda
                from bilägare)
    loop
        if o.bilar_ägda <= 1 -- replaced it from pnr_fordon and <= is used for 0 or 1 car
            then v_suffix := 'bil'; -- := and ; is used here and in next statement
            else v_suffix := 'bilar';
        end if;
        dbms_output.put_line(o.pnr || ', ' || o.fnamn || ', ' || o.enamn
            || ' Äger: ' || o.pnr_fordon || ' bil' || v_suffix);
    end loop;
end;
/
```